# hyperHTML seemingly fails to call (attach?) onload events

Tags: hyperhtml

I'm attempting to dynamically conditionally load additional JavaScript while using hyperHTML. I've narrowed the failure to the `onload` event.

Here's an attempt at a minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```js
class ScriptLoader extends hyperHTML.Component {
  onload(event) {
    notie.alert({ text: "notie loaded" });
  }
  render() {
    return this.html`
      <script
        src=https://unpkg.com/notie
        type=text/javascript
        async=false
        onload=${this}
      />
    `;
  }
}

hyperHTML.bind(document.body)`
  <h2>onload test (notie)</h2>
  ${new ScriptLoader}
`;
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/hyperhtml@2.4.0/min.js"></script>
```

As you can see `notie.alert` is never called, even though the `script` is inserted correctly.

This some process works correctly using vanilla JS with `addEventListener('load',` and `appendChild(`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** this was an issue with Firefox and Web (Safari) considering death nodes scripts injected via innerHTML, even if through a template and after imported.

That means the issue was not with the `onload` per-se, rather the fact no network request was ever triggered so that `onload` would never happen indeed.

As you can verify now in the [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/QORGYV?editors=0010) eaxmple, which uses your exact same snippet I rewrite in part to make SO happy about me linking Code Pen, both Firefox and Safari, as well as Chrome and Edge should work just fine.

```
hyperHTML.bind(document.body)`
  <h2>onload test (notie)</h2>
  ${new ScriptLoader}
`;
```

I am keeping part of the old edit just to make you, or any other reader, aware of a little caveat that JSX affectionate might overuse.

---

There is one thing you should be careful with: hyperHTML does not parse HTML and `<script/>` is not valid HTML.

You are risking to find nodes where you shouldn't if you don't close non-void tags regularly, and this is beyond hyperHTML capabilities, unfortunately how HTML works in general.

```
<p/><b>unexpected</b>
```

I understand for this demo case you had to do that or the parse would complain with a closing script in the page but remember, you can always do this instead, when necessary:

```
`<script><\x2fscript>`
```

Comment: Thank you for resolving this issue so quickly, and thank you for the hex encoding tip (very useful).